# Checking submitted token against authenticity token in database with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, controller, devise

I'm using a Chrome extension to send data to my Rails app (the staged_images controller). So I have a form that sends the data, along with an authentication token. Each user has a token which is generated by Devise, and is saved into the Users table. What I need to do now is receive that data in the controller and check the submitted token against the one stored in the Users table.

So the create action in my controller should look something like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:staged_image][:user_id])
    if @user.authentication_token == submitted_token # this is pseudo code, don't know exactly what to say here
      # execute code
    else
      # raise error
    end
end
```

I'm just having trouble with the specifics of how to check the one token against the other. I'm a newbie. Help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass to the token controller and have a filter on the top and pass a `auth_token` in your call (`http://yoursite/staged_images?auth_token=YOUR_STORED_TOKEN'`).

```
class staged_images < ApplicationController  

   before_filter :authenticate_user!

end
```

Devise will raise an exception if the token is invalid.

You can access the user information with the helper `current_user`